# Array only deletes half of the duplicated values

Tags: c

I was trying to make an animal shelter as practice for c programming and I wanted to remove a duplicated name from an array, but it does not seem to be working.

This is my code:

```
void deleteAnimalByName(char *animalName, int *nrOfAnimals, ANIMAL *animalArray)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < *nrOfAnimals; i ++)
   {
       if(strcmp((animalArray + i)->Name, animalName) == 0)
       {
           for(int j = i; j < *nrOfAnimals - 1; j++)
           {
            char removeDataFromAnimal[] = "";

            (animalArray + j)->Age = (animalArray + j - i)->Age;
            strcpy((animalArray + i)->Name, removeDataFromAnimal);
            (animalArray + j)->Species = (animalArray + j - i)->Species;
           }
           *nrOfAnimals = *nrOfAnimals -1;
       }
   }
```

This is the outcome:

Animals in shelter: 1

Name:

Species: Dog

Age: 5

Comment: If you modify the target integer of `i` in the loop, with `*nrOfAnimals = *nrOfAnimals -1;`, you will stop looping before the end of the array.

Comment: what do you mean by this?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? What are the contents of the array before and after calling this function? Telling us just the outcome isn't helpful if we don't know what it starts as.

Comment: yes of course. it starts out as an empty array, the user has to add an animal with an name, age and species. but when an animal with the same name gets deleted, they both should get deleted. don't know if this is helpful, english isn't my native language

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? The full values of the inputs to this function, and what the result is afterwards.

Comment: Suppose the array has 10 elements, that is the value of `*nrOfAnimals`. Suppose you have 5 duplicates in positions from 1 to 5. If each time you find a duplicate you decrease that variable, when `i=6` you will have `*nrOfAnimals=5`, and the loop will stop.

Comment: Also your removal doesn't seem correct. Are you trying to shift all the values after the element that's being removed? You are changing the name and species of `animalArray[j]` but aren't modifying its name.

Comment: this is what it's supposed to do: It should be possible to remove an animal with a specified name. If more animals with the same name exist, it should remove all the animal with the same name. 

I think that the code i wrote is wrong, but i don't know how to fix this. the outcome shows that the names that are both the same gets deleted, but everything else stays.

Comment: `(animalArray + j)->Age = (animalArray + j - i)->Age;` so since `j` starts at `i`, for the first entry, you copy `animalArray[0]->Age` to `animalArray[i]->Age` - was that the intent?

Comment: not really, but i don;t know another way to remove it from the array

Answer (score 0):

i know changed my code to this, still don't know why it only deletes one animal right now:

```
void deleteAnimalByName(char *animalName, int *nrOfAnimals, ANIMAL *animalArray)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < *nrOfAnimals; i ++)
   {
       if(strcmp((animalArray + i)->Name, animalName) == 0)
       {
           for(int j = i; j < *nrOfAnimals - 1; j++)
           {
            animalArray[j] = animalArray[j + i];
           }
           (*nrOfAnimals)--;
       }
   }

}
```